# Display posts on Elementor that belong to Page Author ID (Page Creator)

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Hi
 I wanted to use elementor widgets and show some custom posts for current post author. I thought maybe with **Query ID** in Elemntor I can do it easily so the widget will show **some custom posts of "Page Author"
 
I wrote a query that show the custom-post-type1 and custom-post-type2 of current post author
My query doesn't work unfortunately

```
function mzba_post_types( $query ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', [ 'custom-post-type1', 'custom-post-type2' ] );
    $author = get_queried_object_id();
                    
                    if( is_single() ){
                        $author = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );
                    }
                    $query_vars[ 'author' ] = $author;
}
add_action( 'elementor/query/{$query_id}', 'mzba_post_types' );
```

anyone can help for a query (or any other way) that shows **the Page creator custom posts** in Elementor?

thank you so so mcuh for helping

Answer (score -1):

This might help you. However, you can try pre-build filters as well to achieve this.

https://elementor.com/blog/introducing-advanced-query-control/

Comment: Thank you so much Unfortunately it just work with elementor Post widget. with other widgets which have Query ID (Give your Query a custom unique id to allow server side filtering) Thank you so much for commenting :)